# Communicating with a completely separate vue component

Tags: vue.js

Let's say I have a webshop and a shopping cart in the header that can unfold and remove things etc etc. Standard fare. Implementing this in vue seems easy enough.

Now I press a button somewhere else on the page (Where on the page doesn't matter) - how do I get the cart to update?

In other words, how do I connect an arbitrary event to a vue instance? I imagine making the entire page into a huge vue instance would work but that smells fishy, and would probably hit performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that having Vue control only part of an application is what is fishy, but you can refer to your Vue instance externally. If it has a method named `updateCart` and you created it like

```
const vueInstance = new Vue(...);
```

then you could call `vueInstance.updateCart(whatever);` in your click handler.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's fishy because I'm thinking of a mostly server-generated website, not anything close to an SPA. Anyway, methods just live under the `methods` key in the object passed to `new Vue()`?

Comment: Methods are specified using `methods` as a key, but in the Vue object, they are top-level members. Note that I didn't say `vueInstance.methods.updateCart`.